# Is there a difference between ''when on'' and ''while on''?

Tags: difference, phrases

Is it OK to say:

> When on holiday, I learnt how to swim.

Is there a difference if we say:

> While on holiday, I learnt how to swim.

Comment: To my ear, the *when* version has a bit more of the feeling of “every time I was on holiday.” The intended meaning is obvious enough, so there’s little chance of anyone’s actually interpreting the sentence that way, especially because it would be pretty nonsensical. But I do think that your *while* version sounds better. Chalk it up to personal preference?

Answer (score 1):

The word "while" references a *period* of time, however long or short that might be.  The word "when" references a *single event* or *point* in time.

It is very rare that someone is able to swim instantly (I once witnessed a 22-year-old young lady who did), as it usually requires some mental training that takes a certain amount of time.  Since the swimming skill requires a period of time to acquire, the word "while" is more applicable.

"When on holiday," however, could be used to distinguish between one's holiday time and one's work or study time.  Using "when on holiday" with learning to swim would imply that one had not had opportunity to devote to the activity during one's regular non-holiday time.  Saying "when on holiday," however, leaves it open, in this case, to any or all holiday opportunities: the learning period might span more than one holiday.

If one has learned to swim during a single holiday period, using "while" would be more natural.  Either one can technically be correct, as a holiday can be seen as a period of time, or as a specific event.  It becomes a matter of focus: whether to emphasize the particular *period* of time, or whether to emphasize the *quality* of that time (i.e. "holiday" time).

Comment: I dispute that *when* fits only moments in time. Consider sentences like “When Nick is in town, he stays at the Hilton.”

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum And in the example you use, you are not using "when" to address a specific time: you are using it to specify a _quality_ for that time, in this case, you address Nick's _town time_ (time in town).  I addressed that usage in my third paragraph.

Comment: Hey, @Biblasia, I am merely taking issue with the absolute claim you make in your first paragraph: “The word ‘when’ references a *single event* or *point* in time.” [emphasis in the original] Perhaps you’d like to tweak it because in its present form it seems to contradict what you say further on.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I see what you are highlighting, but I don't see a reasonable way to improve upon what I presented.  If I say "typically references," I am saying that "when" is seldom used in the other manner--which might not be true at all.  If I add more to the sentence to accommodate the other usage of when which I explained later, it complicates the sentence and makes it confusing.  As worded, the sentence is correct.  "When" _does_ serve in that capacity.  I am not saying that it serves in **only** that capacity, simply that it does get used this way.

Comment: I see your difficulty in finding a good fix. And I agree that the sentence in isolation does not explicitly say “**only** references a single…” But the sentence is not situated alone; readers encounter it in the context of your previous sentence, and taken together the pair of sentences give every impression of a sharp dichotomy. How about “often references”?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum In the context of those two first sentences, the "sharp dichotomy" is intentional.  "When" should not be used for a *period* of time, which is what "while" addresses.  Saying "often" might imply that "when" could _sometimes_ be used like "while"--which is precisely what I am explaining against.  Perhaps you have a better way of explaining.  I would encourage you to post your own answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147978/discussion-between-paul-tanenbaum-and-biblasia).